# Convergence of arguments in optimization

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, maximum-likelihood, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

This question is motivated by non-parametric maximum likelihood estimation is statistics but I guess it applies more generally to any optimization problem.

Let $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$ be a data sample and $F$ be a non-parametric class of densities. In non-parametric MLE, one wants to solve

$\max_{f \in F}\ell(f):=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \log f(x_i)$

Now, in general, for two topological spaces $Z$ and $Y$ and a mapping $g:X \rightarrow Y$, the point $a\in Y$ is a limit of $g$ at $x_0$, if for any neighbourhood $V$ of $a$ there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that for any $x \in U-\{x_0\}$, $g(x) \in V$.

I am trying to translate this to the MLE problem. It seems like my $g$ here should be $\ell: F \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ because this is the function I am maximising. However, what confuses me is that in MLE problems, we are less interested in the exact value of $\ell(f)$ but really the argmax $\hat{f}$. So the convergence I am interested in is how to ensure that if there is a sequence of functions $(f_k)$ such that $\ell(f_k)\rightarrow \ell(\hat{f})$, we get that $f_k \rightarrow \hat{f}$. So it seems like what I need is some kind of inverse $\ell^{-1}$ but this is not well-defined (even if I think of $\ell$ as $\ell: F \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, $\ell^{-1}$ still needs to take finitely many values and somehow translate that into a function).

I feel like I am facing a chicken-and-egg problem. What am I missing?

Comment: In general, you won't be able to infer what you want. Imagine that $F$ is a vector space of a big (possibly, infinite) dimension $N$. Your objective function, however, only depends on the finitely many evaluations $f(x_1),\ldots,f(x_n)$. So, for the prescribed values $f(x_1) = y_1,\ldots,f(x_n) = y_n$ (e.g., values that give you the maximum) you would generally have an $(N-n)$-dimensional affine subspace of functions in $F$ that give you these values.

Comment: well, that's kind of exactly my question. It doesn't seem like it should be possible, but people do optimization over function spaces, so there is something that I am missing

Comment: In control theory, one optimizes over function spaces, but the objective depends on the whole $f$ then, not on finitely many evaluations at prescribed points. Maybe you could give some pointers to the relevant background theory.